# Raspberry pi 2(IoT) httpclient error: The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect c#

Tags: c#, ssl, iot

I am trying to make my Raspberry pi running on windows IoT get information from a webservice i have on an internal server.
To achieve this I am using UWP in visual studio community 2015.

Context:
I have a sql database that stores the information, and it is gathered and made readble by an
 mvc with an APIController that packets the information up and sends it out. In my UWP i use a system.net HttpClient
to get information

The problem:
using this bit of code:

```
// httpClientHandler sends in my user arguments since the server is passwordprotected
using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my.servers.dns");
                var task = client.GetAsync("/pathTo/api/packet");
                HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
                var task2 = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PacketInformation[]>();
                data = task2.Result;
            }
```

When i compile and run my program on my laptop that IS connected to the domain it works fine

When i compile and run my program on the IOT which is not connected to the domain but i added the ip to the hosts file using

```
add-content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts "192.168.abc.def internal.server.DNSName"
```

it sends out a certificate error, and the code returns "The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect"

Does anyone know why this happens ? it should be sending the same information all the way through.

Comment: Just a thought: does the RasPi run with the correct date and time? I once had a similar issue with a Beaglebone Black...

Comment: the date was correct and the time aswell, but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add the internal CA certificate to the raspberry pi's trusted root certification authorities store. (domain joined pc's automatically do this for you).

1. Download the certificate authority certificate from the server (which can be located at C:\windows\system32\certserv\certenroll\MyInternalCA.cer) onto the raspberry pi.
2. SSH into the raspberry pi, Import the certificate into the trusted root certification store and then reboot the raspberry pi. Here is an example of this: certmgr.exe -add MyInternalCA.cer -s -r localMachine root

Now your raspberry pi will trust the internal CA for communicating to the website using TLS.